# Getting rid of white space between name, number and height

Tags: python, file, txt

I have txt file like this;

```
name lastname     17      189cm
```

How do I get it to be like this?

```
name lastname, 17, 189cm
```

Comment: What have you attempted? Do you have any sample code you have tried that we could help fix to get it to work?

Comment: Need an MRE or at least some code to show what you have attempted or even began.

Comment: What is the actual separator between the fields? Could it be TAB?

Comment: Why is there no comma between `name` and `lastname` in the result? How is that whitespace distinguished  from the others?

Comment: @Barmar `repr` of OPs original text contains no `TAB`s

Comment: @Jab That could just be due to the way he copied it.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = 'name lastname     17      189cm'
out = ', '.join(text.rsplit(maxsplit=2)) # if sep is not provided then any consecutive whitespace is a separator
print(out) # name lastname, 17, 189cm
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace multiple spaces (or tabs) with a comma:

```
import re

text = 'name lastname     17      189cm'
re.sub(r'\s\s+|\t', ', ', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.strip` and `str.split`:

```
>>> my_string = 'name lastname     17      189cm'
>>> s = list(map(str.strip, my_string.split()))
>>> ', '.join([' '.join(s[:2]), *s[2:] ])
'name lastname, 17, 189cm'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = "name lastname       17         189cm"
re.sub("[ ]{2,}",", ", s)
```

PS: for the first problem you proposed, I had the following solution:

```
s = "name lastname 17 189cm"
s[::-1].replace(" ",",", 2)[::-1]
```